# PHP retrieving all the type array in the $_FILES array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to find a way to drill down into the $_FILES array and retrieve the [type] => Array in its entirety. I have tried a number of approaches can't get anywhere with this:

```
$result = preg_grep('/\image\b/', $_FILES);
```

When I output $result in this manner:

```
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
```

I get the following:

```
Array (
```

)

Which is of course useless. I've been going through the Manual, looking at all the array functions, but haven't found anything that works. Is there a PHP function for this? Any help would be very much appreciated!
Cheers,

shackleton

PS I've also tried to use:

```
foreach ($_FILES['userfile']['type'] as $key => $value) {
```

to create my own array with both the key and value of each file uploaded. The problem with that is the variable will not create an array with more than one - [0] - index because the array construct is referencing the variable. That seems to be a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending multiple files, you should iterate using $_FILES only, as this:

```
$types=array();
foreach($_FILES as $filename=>$arrayofvalues){
  $types[]=$arrayofvalues['type'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Holla Ricardo,
Thanks so much, that works like a charm. I had to go find a way to flatten the resulting array, but did find a function online that works. I had been looking for that function too for several days. Here's what I came up with:

```
 // Create an array of only the file type
$types = array();
foreach ($_FILES as $filename => $arrayofvalues) {
    $types[] = $arrayofvalues['type'];
}

// Create a sub-array of types
foreach($types as $subArray) {
    foreach($subArray as $val){
        $simple[] = $val;
    }
}

echo "Simple images array:";
echo '<pre>';
print_r($simple);
echo '</pre>';
"<br />";

// Get the key & value of just image files
$images = preg_grep('/\image\b/', $simple);

// Use the differenc array function to find the indices I want
$dif = array_diff($simple, $images);

echo "Difference:";
echo '<pre>';
print_r($dif);
echo '</pre>';
"<br />";
```

Of course the print_r() is only so I can see what the code is producing. The output looks like this:
[html Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKsgS.jpg)

Thanks again for you assistance!

Cheers,

shackleton

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is a bit heavy-handed with the foreach loops.  I have prepared a shorter way to accomplish your task.

Using this array:

```
$FILES=array(
  "file1"=>array("type"=>array("text/plain")),
  "file2"=>array("type"=>array("image/tiff")),
  "file3"=>array("type"=>array("")),
  "file4"=>array("type"=>array("image/png")),
  "file5"=>array("type"=>array("image/gif")),
  "file6"=>array("type"=>array("image/jpeg"))
);
```

You can have your output with these two one-liners:

```
$simple_images=array_column(array_column($FILES,"type"),0);
var_export($simple_images);

echo "\n";

$difference=array_filter($simple_images,function($v){return strpos($v,"image")===false;});
var_export($difference);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'text/plain',
  1 => 'image/tiff',
  2 => '',
  3 => 'image/png',
  4 => 'image/gif',
  5 => 'image/jpeg',
)
array (
  0 => 'text/plain',
  2 => '',
)
```

Referring to your `preg_grep()` function, it is best to avoid using regex when another string manipulation will suffice.  This is will improve performance.

Comment: Thank you mickmackusa, I'll start messing with this. In the last week, I've learned all kinds of useful stuff for arrays. I hadn't used them much in the past. You code does look very straight forward. Thanks again!